# Xcode git commit fails on project stored in iCloud Drive

Tags: xcode, git, icloud

I just moved my Xcode projects to iCloud Drive to see if I could work on them across computers. So far, everything works perfectly… except git. I can't pull up the history and trying to commit gives me an error like this:
[image]

I've heard many people say that iCloud Drive is problematic and I should use GitHub, but I'm already paying for iCloud and literally all my other files are in there. That isn't to say I wouldn't be open to switching, but **I'd like to know why these errors are occurring** so I can make an informed decision.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm just spitballing here, but is there any chance it's looking for Asset.xcassets in the wrong Slidefari folder? I notice that your project folder is called Slidefari, and so is the parent of the Asset.xcassets folder.

It's been a while since I had to use XCode, and by "use" I mean "tear my hair out over," and I've only ever used GitHub for CVS, but maybe changing the name of the project folder will remove one variable? (And probably break your project BECAUSE SOFTWARE DESIGN, AMIRITE???)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll look into that. That being said I think the commit failing is a symptom of the real problem. Git works fine on the computer the project was created on…

Answer (score 0):

Judging based on the fact that the repository works fine on the computer which it was created on, it sounds to me like some sort of git authentication issue.

It depends how your repository authenticates too.  Many repo's have you generate an ssh key with keygen and submit that.  I'm not 100% certain how that security works, but I'd venture to guess that the certificates and such involved are tied to your computer on a 1:1 basis.

I was thinking about moving my Xcode project to the iCloud drive but I'm concerned about the risks.  I'd be curious to know if you found a solution.  Thanks.